# get meta data using get_results in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get a json print with some of my posts in a specific category.

I want ex.: *title*, *category* and then some meta-data with the keyes *lat* and *lon* (coordinates).

Result / json:
`[{"meta_key1":"meta_value1","meta_key2":"meta_value2","post_title":"The title","post_cat":"cat_ID")"}`

Case / example:
`[{"lat":"55.395263","lon":"10.385723","post_title":"Mammas Pizza","post_cat":"Fast Food")"}`

Here is one of my tests - what is the next step in my query?:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM $wpdb->posts a LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta b ON b.post_id = a.ID");

    if (!$result['error']) {
        print json_encode($result);
    } else {
        errorJson('fail');
    }
```

Comment: are there any info stored in the result variable. Do this and posts the result: console.log($result);

Comment: I don't understand. What did you mean about 'any info'? Any meta-fields or?

Comment: Rephrasing my question... what results do you get from your "print json_encode($result);" statement?

Comment: I will get a list with all posts in a specific category (ex. food) and all the posts there will be listed in the json should look like this:´{"lat":"55.395263","lon":"10.385723","post_title":"Mammas Pizza","post_cat":"Fast Food")"}´

Answer (score 0):

First we define the function to get post categories in a nice array.

```
function get_post_categories()
{
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $cats =array(); $counter=0;
    foreach ($categories as $cat)
        $cats[$counter] = $cat->cat_name;

    return implode(',',$cats);
}
```

Then we define a function that gets our posts and packs info in a nice JSON array.

```
function get_my_json_posts()
{
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $posts = array(); $i= 0;
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $posts[$i++] = array(
            'title' => get_the_title();
            'categories' => get_post_categories();
            'lat' => get_post_meta('lat');
            'lon' => get_post_meta('lon');
        );
    endwhile;

    return json_encode($posts);
}
```

If you're having troubles with $args you can see all the parameters here: [Class reference-> WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Hmm, no results with your code. First I change the ; to , in the arrays. But will these code work on a page outside wordpress (of course with "require( 'wp-load.php' );" in he top? I want a list with all posts in a category (ex. food) and all the posts there will be listed in the json should look like this:´{"lat":"55.395263","lon":"10.385723","post_title":"Mammas Pizza","post_cat":"Fast Food")"}´

Comment: This is my code right now - and it give no result, whats wrong: `

function get_my_json_posts()
{
    $args = array ( 'post_type' => 'post' , 'post_status' => 'publish' );
    $posts = array(); 
 $i= $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $posts[$i++] = array(
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'lat' => get_post_meta('lat'),
            'lon' => get_post_meta('lon')
        ); 
    endwhile;
    return json_encode($posts);
} `